# Why do I keep getting this error every time? ReferenceError: Can't find variable: greet

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, scope, arrow-functions

This is the simple practice code

```js
const greet = (person) => {
    return `Hey ${person}!`;
}
```

When I call greet, it keeps bringing the above error. This also applies to almost all the code I write and when i call them i get the same reference error and that the variable cannot be found. What I am I doing wrong?

I have tried

```js
const greet = (person) => {
    return `Hey ${person}!`;
}
greet()
```

and then calling it. It still brings the same error. I know its something simple but I just can't place my finger on it

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Given "it keeps bringing the above error", what is "it"? Show how you're calling this, and ideally, force yourself to run through the [mcve] exercise so that you can show code in a runnable snippet that shows your problem off, _if_ you don't discover the problem all on your own while running through that exercise.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: [Hey undefined!](https://jsfiddle.net/a1rq806y/)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your function declaration. That's how we declare a function in Js using the arrow function.

```js
// Declaration of Function

const greet = (person) =>{
 console.log(`Hey There ${person}`);
}
```

This should work perfectly as long as you provide the value for the person.

```js
greet(); // This will give, Hey there undefined
greet("joseph"); // This will provide, Hey there joseph
```

[image: You can see the same by running it in console]

If you are getting an exception saying that the `greet()` function doesn't exist ensure that you declare it before the function you are using it. Because arrow functions should be declared before the place you use it, they have different behavior compared to normal functions in JavaScript.

```js
// If using arrow syntax, *must* declare functions beforehand
const greet = (person)=> {
 console.log(`Hey There ${person}`);
}

const useGreet = () =>{
 greet("joseph");
}

function main(){
 useGreet();
 doSomething();
}

// If using function syntax can declare functions anywhere
function doSomething(){
 console.log("Do Something");
}
```